How to exclude squirrel.mac framework from getting included in electron app for dmg file
I am getting error for squirrel.mac while publishing dmg file to app store.
we are not using auto update for our app.
so any idea How to completely disable AutoUpdate in Mac/How to exclude squirrel.mac framework from getting included in electron app for dmg file
i tried to remove the squirrel framework folder from app content, but it is not allowing me to open the app

It is Resolved after creating MAS build.
